# Chef create policygroup

Tags: chef-infra, policy, policyfiles

I want to bootstrap a node with Policyfile, but I need a policy group to perform this. However, the chef's documentation does not mention how to create a policy group. There is a command for deleting, but none for creation:
https://docs.chef.io/policyfile.html#chef-delete-policy-group

I tried too google it, with no luck.
Any help will be appreciated!

Regards,
Marek

Answer (score 1):

Policy groups aren't a thing you have to create. They are summoned into existence when you `chef push` to them. they also don't actually hold any information, it's more like a "tag" on the compiled policy when uploaded rather than a Big Fancy Object like we use for other things in Chef.

Answer (score 0):

https://blog.chef.io/2015/08/18/policyfiles-a-guided-tour/

An except from the above blog that you will find useful:

"...

```
chef provision staging --sync -n aar-staging-01 -o port=8000
```

That will sync our local policy lock to a policy group called ‘staging’
(creating that policy group in the process), then run an embedded Chef
Client which creates a VM (via Chef Provisioning), configures it and
converges it...
"

So it looks like chef provision  is the syntax you're looking for.